# how to show a activity(login screen) under android navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-listview

Basically my requirement is to show a login screen to the user using the sliding out navigation like Facebook slide out menu.

I tried the navigation drawer example available on android developers website it shows only using list view. Can any one tell me please is it possible to show a activity using navigation drawer?

please see the image below:

[image]

could any one please help me to get rid of this?

Comment: use this https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu instead of navigation drawer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

i have edited [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) Example download it. change it below way.

in Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    // private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private int left;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        left = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame_new, new LeftFragment(),
                        "LeftFragment").commit();

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        // mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        // R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        // mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
        mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
        R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
        R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
        // view
        //boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        // mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        // mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
     */
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet,
                    container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources()
                    .getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(
                    planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()), "drawable",
                    getActivity().getPackageName());
            ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image))
                    .setImageResource(imageId);
            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!--
         As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
    -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!--
         android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view.
    -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame_new"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

LeftFragment.java

```
public class LeftFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, null);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

}
```

activity_login.xml --> do your design whatever you want.

**you have to handle open & close Drawer**

---

**Edited 29/12/13 :**

Yes you can do it without actionbar.

i have just add this line `getActionBar().hide();` at end of onCreate() in MainActivity.

You have to use slide(swipe) to open Login page

Comment: I have one more question on this, is it possible to do this navigation drawer with out action bar?

Answer (score 0):

android widget for drawer -> `SlidingDrawer` But u cannot use it only for an activity. better approach i would prefer for u is use of fragments.