# how to implement navigation drawer without action bar but opens the navigation screen with a button on main screen?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

navigation drawer app that have login screen on its left_drawer fragment (see link:  [how to show a activity(login screen) under android navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798136/how-to-show-a-activitylogin-screen-under-android-navigation-drawer) ), I want to open this login screen from the main screen using a button and also don't want the action bar on navigation drawer. Can any one please help me with this?

Thanks In advance!!

Answer (score 7):

It's quite simple actually. Easier than with ActionBar. I'm writing the answer with almost simplest of layouts

make your xml something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- This is how your main page will look, just 2 buttons -->

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:onClick="onLeft"
        android:text="left" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="onRight"
        android:text="right" />
    </RelativeLayout>

<!-- Left Drawrer -->

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/whatYouWantInLeftDrawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />
    <!-- you can have many more widgets here like buttons or labels -->
    </RelativeLayout>

<!-- Right Drawrer -->

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/whatYouWantInRightDrawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
    <!-- you can have many more widgets here like buttons or labels -->
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then make your activity something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout leftRL;
RelativeLayout rightRL;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      I'm removing the ActionBar.
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    leftRL = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.whatYouWantInLeftDrawer);
    rightRL = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.whatYouWantInRightDrawer);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    }

    public  void onLeft(View view)
    {
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(leftRL);
    }

    public  void onRight(View view)
    {
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(rightRL);
    }
}
```

That's it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Navigation Drawer. Very easy to implement and very professional looking. Instead of putting a listview in your Navigation Drawer just create another layout and inflate the layout when your Navigation Drawer is active. You can view information about a Navigation Drawer [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

Your going to find many ways to have a slide out drawer. But your problem is going to be creating a custom layout and inflating it inside the Navigation Drawer.

Best of luck to you!